# File system issue in Azure app service - Unable to create Directories

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

We have a dotnet core application hosted in Azure app service (Windows machine) in our production environment. It consists of two components -

- Email Service
- Business Rules Engine

The Email service downloads all emails first to a folder `Attachments` in the same directory where the application is hosted (`D:\home\wwwroot\`). For each email, a separate directory (with a guid value) is created under the `Attachments` directory.

The Business Rules engine accesses that folder and uses the email and it's attachments. Once done, we clear out all contents from the `Attachments` directory.

The problem we're seeing is that after a certain number of emails are processed, all of a sudden our application is unable to create directories under the `Attachments` folder. The statement

```
Directory.CreateDirectory({path})
```

throws an error saying the specified path could not be found.

The only way we've been able to resolve this is to restart the app service and it again happily goes on it's way creating directories, processing emails until it fails again in a day or so 8-|

What we've tried -

- Ours was a multithreaded app, so assuming that maybe one thread is holding a lock on the filesystem due to incorrect or incomplete disposing of resources, we changed it to single threaded processing
- Where the directories were being created, we used `DirectoryInfo`, so tried using `DirectoryInfo.Refresh()` after every directory deletion, creation etc
- Wherever `FileStream` was being used, we've added explicit `.Dispose()` statements to dispose of the `FileStream`
- Called `GC.Collect()` at the end of each run of our service

I suspect this issue is due to the Azure environment but we've not been able to identify what is causing this issue. Has anybody had any such issues and if so how was it resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes to my code based on what I read in these links here which gives a good summary of the storage system in Azure app service -

- https://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/2017/12/13/how-to-manually-create-a-directory-on-your-azure-app-service/
- https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system

`D:\local` directory points to a folder that is accessible only to that instance of the service, instead of what I was using earlier which is shared among instances - `D:\home`.

So I changed the code to resolve the `%Temp%` environment variable, which resolved to `D:\local\Temp` and then used that location to store the downloaded Emails.

So far multiple testing runs have been executed without any exceptions related to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, based on your issue description,it does look to be a sandbox restriction. To provide more more on this, the standard/native Azure Web Apps run in a secure environment called a sandbox. Each app runs inside its own sandbox, isolating its execution from other instances on the same machine as well as providing an additional degree of security and privacy which would otherwise not be available.

Azure App Service provides pre-defined application stacks on Windows like ASP.NET or Node.js, running on IIS. The preconfigured Windows environment locks down the operating system from administrative access, software installations, changes to the global assembly cache, and so on (see Operating system functionality on Azure App Service). If your application requires more access than the preconfigured environment allows, you can deploy a custom Windows container instead.

Symbolic link creation: While sandboxed applications can follow/open existing symbolic links, they cannot create symbolic links (or any other reparse point) anywhere.

Additionally, you can check if the files has read-only attribute, to check for this, go to Kudu Console (({yoursite}.scm.azurewebsites.net)) and run attrib somefile.txt, and check if it includes the R (read-only) attribute.